# How to insert many Child/parent items with a singe query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

Suppose we have the following SQL Server table structures:

```
MainItem
........
ID (int)
Total (money)

SubItem
........
ID (int)
MainItemID (int)
Price (money)
```

We need to generate thousands of MainItems, with each MainItem having dozens of SubItems, and input this at once in the database.
Currently our code looks something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, int> oldToNewIDs = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach(MainItem mainItem in GeneratedMainItems)
{
    int oldID = mainItem.ID;
    mainItem.Update();
    oldToNewIDs.Add(oldID, mainItem.ID);
}
foreach (SubItem subItem in GeneratedSubItems)
{
    fi.MainItemID = oldToNewIDs[fi.MainItemID];
    subItemsToInsert.Add(fi);
}

InsertAllSubItemsAtOnce(subItemsToInsert);
```

The code for inserting alle subitems at once looks like:

```
string sql = @"
INSERT INTO SubItems (MainItemID, Price) VALUES (1, 100)
INSERT INTO SubItems (MainItemID, Price) VALUES (1, 50)
INSERT INTO SubItems (MainItemID, Price) VALUES (2, 20)
...
";
UpdateDB(sql);
```

The problem we currently face, is that in one occasion, only half of the subitems were inserted. So we ended up with wrong totals and subitems. I don't exactly understand how this could happen, but my guess is that something went wrong in sql server?

What we want to achieve, is that we insert everyting (main and subitems) at once, and if something goes wrong, the insert is aborted, so we don't end up with invalid data.
How can this be done?

Comment: If you only got half, it means there was a problem in the *code*. Either you passed only half the values, or there was an error that wasn't logged and "hidden" through a `catch{}`. Since you don't explain what `Update`, `Add`, `UpdateDB` or `InsertAllSubItemsAtOnce` do, it's impossible to help.

Comment: You can wrap all the `insert/update` in 1 transaction to make sure either all or none are inserted

Comment: Either make sure you wrap all operations in a transaction, or *don't* try to write such code yourself. Use an ORM like Entity Framework

Comment: Furthermore, if you have many records to insert in the same table, you don't need to issue  multiple INSERT commands. You can pass multiple records in the `VALUES` clause, eg `VALUES (1,100),(1,50),(2,20)`. INSERT is atomic so all values will be inserted or all will fail

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : how could this be a problem in the code, since  we just call 'myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()' with a single sql query?

Comment: @RunCMD because the query is wrong, because the values are wrong (duplicates, constraint violations?), because the calls before that `ExecuteNonQuery` are wrong. How can we know? You didn't even post the error messages. If you don't have any, there's another bug in the code that hides error messages

Comment: @RunCMD in any case, inserting related data into databases from any .NET language is very well documented since 2002. With plain-vanilla ADO.NET you'd use DataSets. In the last 10+ years, it's ORMs like EF and NH, or microORMs like Dapper. For bulk inserts, it's SqlBulkCopy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your workload into a transaction

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql , conn, conn.BeginTransaction());

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch(System.Exception ex)
    {
        cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
        throw ex;
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```